# How to connect my app with the database server

Tags: python, sqlite, server

I made a program with using `sqlite3` and `pyqt` modules. The program can be used by different persons simultaneously. Actually I searched but I did not know and understand the concept of server. How can i connect this program with a server. Or just the computers that have connections with the server is enough to run the program simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do u want to connect to sqlite database server? SQLite Is Serverless. It stores your data in a file.
U should use maria db for db server. Or u can store your sqlite database file in a network shared drive or cloud or...

Comment: Okey i understand,  but is the type of database server  important such as(Microsoft server or mysql)?

Comment: i don't understand, what do u want to do with the database. But i think yes. MS-SQL is not free. You can use [Sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It's easy  to change the database later

Comment: well people entry the changes with the program into database and other user see this changes and maybe do changes. so in order to do this, computers must connect with each other right

Comment: reading and writing are basic functions of  a database. u can use all database server. my suggestion is MariaDB for database server. It's easy to install and use. And SQlalchemy for the lib in your python code

Comment: The program must use with different users usimultaneously. How can i  achieve that bro? I did not understand the server thing

Comment: there are the lock function in MySQL. so that if some one write something in a table, will be the table locked. and more. so can Multi-user work at the same time. U can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621303/how-do-i-lock-read-write-to-mysql-tables-so-that-i-can-select-and-then-insert-wi

Comment: Or can i handle this with using ms access for multiple user.

Comment: yes, u can do it with ms access. more infos here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672077/setting-up-an-ms-access-db-for-multi-user-access. But i think, that ms access is not a right database server. it's difficult to scale